# How can I reflect a graphic across a line?

Tags: graphics, animation, geometry

I would like to make an animation that shows where a graphic (square, circle etc) would be after it is reflected over a line.
Thanks

Comment: Have you seen `ReflectionTransform[]` already?

Comment: Thanks, this is helping.  I'll post something if I get it working.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a solution using `ReflectionTransform[]`. Here's my code:

```
TabView[{
"Square" -> 
  Manipulate[Graphics[
{{Opacity[1], Red, Rectangle[{a,b},{c,d}]}, Line[{{5, 5}, {5, -5}}],
  GeometricTransformation[{Opacity[1], Blue,Large,Rectangle[{a,b},{c,d}]}, 
   ReflectionTransform[{5, 0}, {5,0}]]}],{a,0,2},{b,0,2},{c,1,4},{d,1,4}
   ], 
  "Triangle" -> 
Manipulate[Graphics[
{{Opacity[1], Red,Triangle[{{a,b},{a,c},{c,b}}]}, Line[{{5, 5}, {5, -5}}],
  GeometricTransformation[{Opacity[1], Blue,Large, Triangle[{{a,b},{a,c},{c,b}}]},  ReflectionTransform[{5, 0}, {5,0}]]}],{a,0,2},{b,0,2},{c,1,5}],
   "Circle" ->
Manipulate[Graphics[
{{Opacity[1], Red,Disk[{a,b},c]}, Line[{{5, 5}, {5, -5}}],
  GeometricTransformation[{Opacity[1], Blue,Large,Disk[{a,b},c]}, 
   ReflectionTransform[{5, 0}, {5,0}]]}], {a, 0,2},{b,0,2},{c,1,4}]

      }]
```

Here's what that code produced:

[image: animation of program]

The sliders adjust the shape's position and size and there are tabs for a triangle reflection, square/rectangle reflection, and circle reflection. The red shape is the starter shape and the blue shape is the reflected shape.

I produced the animation using *Mathematica Online* so it's a little choppy.